# FLASH AS3 - Loop video continuously

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I found this code on the net, and it's almost perfect for my needs - but I need it to continuously loop the clip.

```
var so:  Sound= new Sound();
    var audioChannel: SoundChannel= new SoundChannel();
    var audioTransform: SoundTransform = new SoundTransform();
    var video:Video=new Video(320,240);
    var nc:NetConnection=new NetConnection  ;
    nc.connect(null);
    var ns:NetStream=new NetStream(nc);
    var meta: Object = new Object();
    meta.onMetaData = function(meta:Object){
        trace(meta.duration);
    };
    ns.client=meta;
    addChild(video);
    video.attachNetStream(ns);
    ns.play("vid.flv");
    //clip is a transparent clip  (alpha=0) for the entire scene
    clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,mute);
    clip.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,unmute);
    function mute(e:MouseEvent) {
        ns.soundTransform=audioTransform;
        audioTransform.volume=0;
    }
    function unmute(e:MouseEvent) {
        ns.soundTransform=audioTransform;
        audioTransform.volume=1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop a video stream in AS3:

1. Listen for the streams NET_STATUS event.

   ```
   //ns is a netstream object
   ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, streamStatus);
   ```
2. In your `streamStatus` event handler, check if the status code is the video stop event:

   ```
   function streamStatus(status:NetStatusEvent) {
       if (status.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
             //the video has stopped
       }
   }
   ```
3. To loop the video, just seek to the beginning.

   ```
   ns.seek(0);
   ```

---

So this is the final code:

```
    ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, streamStatus);
    ns.play("vid.flv");

    function streamStatus(status:NetStatusEvent) {
        if (status.info.code == "NetStream.Play.Stop") {
            ns.seek(0);
        }
    }
```

To see whatever status codes you can check for, see the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/NetStatusEvent.html#NET_STATUS).